# Finding first and last index of some value in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, search

Is there any built-in methods that are part of lists that would give me the first and last index of some value, like:

```
verts.IndexOf(12.345)
verts.LastIndexOf(12.345)
```

Comment: I am reading them too, but knowing nothing about python makes things harder. I find its syntax very cryptic.

Comment: If your lists are sorted, then you might want to check out the bisect module <http://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html>.

Comment: See the brilliant answer by Dikei here using the built-in functions enumerate and reversed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836425/equivelant-to-rindex-for-lists-in-python

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Sequences have a method `index(value)` which returns index of first occurrence - in your case this would be `verts.index(value)`.

You can run it on `verts[::-1]` to find out the last index. Here, this would be `len(verts) - 1 - verts[::-1].index(value)`

Comment: Thanks, how do you perform list[::-1]?

verts[::-1]?

Comment: Btw verts[::-1] just reverses the list, right? So I have to compensate for the index, right?

Comment: sure, it'll be: len(verts) - 1 - verts[::-1].index(value)

Comment: This can be simplified to guild[::-1][0]

Answer (score 42):

Perhaps the two most efficient ways to find the *last* index:

```
def rindex(lst, value):
    lst.reverse()
    i = lst.index(value)
    lst.reverse()
    return len(lst) - i - 1
```

```
def rindex(lst, value):
    return len(lst) - operator.indexOf(reversed(lst), value) - 1
```

Both take only O(1) extra space and the *two* in-place reversals of the first solution are much faster than creating a reverse copy. Let's compare it with the other solutions posted previously:

```
def rindex(lst, value):
    return len(lst) - lst[::-1].index(value) - 1

def rindex(lst, value):
    return len(lst) - next(i for i, val in enumerate(reversed(lst)) if val == value) - 1
```

Benchmark results, my solutions are the red and green ones:
[image: unshuffled, full range]

This is for searching a number in a list of a million numbers. The x-axis is for the location of the searched element: 0% means it's at the start of the list, 100% means it's at the end of the list. All solutions are fastest at location 100%, with the two `reversed` solutions taking pretty much no time for that, the double-reverse solution taking a little time, and the reverse-copy taking a lot of time.

A closer look at the right end:
[image: unshuffled, tail part]

At location 100%, the reverse-copy solution and the double-reverse solution spend all their time on the reversals (`index()` is instant), so we see that the two in-place reversals are about seven times as fast as creating the reverse copy.

The above was with `lst = list(range(1_000_000, 2_000_001))`, which pretty much creates the int objects sequentially in memory, which is extremely cache-friendly. Let's do it again after shuffling the list with `random.shuffle(lst)` (probably less realistic, but interesting):

[image: shuffled list, full range]

[image: shuffled list, tail part]

All got a lot slower, as expected. The reverse-copy solution suffers the most, at 100% it now takes about 32 times (!) as long as the double-reverse solution. And the `enumerate`-solution is now second-fastest only after location 98%.

Overall I like the `operator.indexOf` solution best, as it's the fastest one for the last half or quarter of all locations, which are perhaps the more interesting locations if you're actually doing `rindex` for something. And it's only a bit slower than the double-reverse solution in earlier locations.

All benchmarks done with CPython 3.9.0 64-bit on Windows 10 Pro 1903 64-bit.

Comment: Be aware that `reverse; index; reverse` is not thread-safe.

Comment: What should be `operator`? Do you have a little exmaple please?

Comment: @TornaxO7 It's the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module from Python's standard library.

Comment: Upvoting for a very high effort answer!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. Could I know of a site or information about making the above graphs? @StefanPochmann

Answer (score 32):

If you are searching for the index of the last occurrence of `myvalue` in `mylist`:

```
len(mylist) - mylist[::-1].index(myvalue) - 1
```

Comment: This will throw a `ValueError` if `myvalue` is not present in `mylist`.

Answer (score 13):

As a small helper function:

```
def rindex(mylist, myvalue):
    return len(mylist) - mylist[::-1].index(myvalue) - 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Python lists have the [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method, which you can use to find the position of the *first* occurrence of an item in a list. Note that `list.index()` raises `ValueError` when the item is not present in the list, so you may need to wrap it in `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    idx = lst.index(value)
except ValueError:
    idx = None
```

To find the position of the *last* occurrence of an item in a list efficiently (i.e. without creating a reversed intermediate list) you can use this function:

```
def rindex(lst, value):
    for i, v in enumerate(reversed(lst)):
        if v == value:
            return len(lst) - i - 1  # return the index in the original list
    return None    

print(rindex([1, 2, 3], 3))     # 2
print(rindex([3, 2, 1, 3], 3))  # 3
print(rindex([3, 2, 1, 3], 4))  # None
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `max` + `enumerate` to get last element occurrence

```py
rindex = max(i for i, v in enumerate(your_list) if v == your_value)
```

Comment: so simple and works well

Answer (score 1):

This method can be more optimized than above:

```python
def rindex(iterable, value):
    try:
        return len(iterable) - next(i for i, val in enumerate(reversed(iterable)) if val == value) - 1
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError
```

Comment: "Optimized" in the sense of being more space-efficient, but it's about 50% slower.

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is the one that perform a "C level reversed loop match".

In pseudo C code:

```
for (int i = len(list) -1; i >= 0; i--)
    if list[i] == value:
        return i
raise NotFound
```

In Python, the right solution should be:

```
def rindex(lst, value):
    # reversed is a buitin backward iterator
    # operator.indexOf can handle this iterator
    # if value is not Found it raises
    #    ValueError: sequence.index(x): x not in sequence
    _ = operator.indexOf(reversed(lst), value)
    # we must fix the resersed index
    return len(lst) - _ - 1
```

**But it would be better to have a reversed index builtin.**

Answer (score 0):

```
s.index(x[, i[, j]])
```

index of the first occurrence of x in s (at or after index i and before index j)

Answer (score 0):

How has nobody suggested to iterate in reverse rather than reversing the array? It's still O(n) because the last occurrence could be at the beginning, but it kind of has to be faster than reversing the list first, no?

```
def rindex(arr, value):
    for i in range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1):
        if arr[i] == value:
            return i
    return -1
```