# How to find the last occurrence of an item in a Python list

Tags: python, list

Say I have this list:

```
li = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "x", "d", "a", "6"]
```

As far as help showed me, there is not a builtin function that returns the last occurrence of a string (like the reverse of `index`). So basically, how can I find the last occurrence of `"a"` in the given list?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you are actually using just single letters like shown in your example, then [`str.rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex) would work handily.  This raises a `ValueError` if there is no such item, the same error class as `list.index` would raise. Demo:

```
>>> li = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "x", "d", "a", "6"]
>>> ''.join(li).rindex('a')
6
```

For the more general case you could use `list.index` on the reversed list:

```
>>> len(li) - 1 - li[::-1].index('a')
6
```

The slicing here creates a *copy* of the entire list. That's fine for short lists, but for the case where `li` is very large, efficiency can be better with a lazy approach:

```
def list_rindex(li, x):
    for i in reversed(range(len(li))):
        if li[i] == x:
            return i
    raise ValueError("{} is not in list".format(x))
```

One-liner version:

```
next(i for i in reversed(range(len(li))) if li[i] == 'a')
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Better than `range(len(li)-1, -1, -1)` is either `reversed(range(len(li)))` or `range(len(li))[::-1]` (they're roughly equivalent too, unlike most comparisons between `reversed` and the reversing slice; modern Py3 `range` can be sliced in reverse to make another lazy `range` that runs backwards, so it's equally performant). Looks like wim went with the former.

Comment: Pythonic version `next(len(a)-i-1 for i, x in enumerate(reversed(a)) if x == 3)`

Answer (score 60):

A one-liner that's like Ignacio's except a little simpler/clearer would be

```
max(loc for loc, val in enumerate(li) if val == 'a')
```

It seems very clear and Pythonic to me: you're looking for the highest index that contains a matching value. No nexts, lambdas, reverseds or itertools required.

Comment: As @Isaac points out this always iterates over all N elements of li.

Comment: a significant downside is the fact you will always iterate through the whole list. you should emphasis that in your answer.

Comment: Use **default=None** to avoid error "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"

  ```max((loc for loc, val in enumerate(li) if val == 'a'), default=None)```

Answer (score 20):

Many of the other solutions require iterating over the entire list.  This does not.

```
def find_last(lst, elm):
  gen = (len(lst) - 1 - i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(lst)) if v == elm)
  return next(gen, None)
```

Edit: In hindsight this seems like unnecessary wizardry.  I'd do something like this instead:

```
def find_last(lst, sought_elt):
    for r_idx, elt in enumerate(reversed(lst)):
        if elt == sought_elt:
            return len(lst) - 1 - r_idx
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> (x for x in reversed(list(enumerate(li))) if x[1] == 'a').next()[0]
6

>>> len(li) - (x for x in enumerate(li[::-1]) if x[1] == 'a').next()[0] - 1
6
```

Answer (score 7):

I like both [wim's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/python-how-to-find-last-occurrence-in-a-list-in-python/6890255#6890255) and [Ignacio's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/python-how-to-find-last-occurrence-in-a-list-in-python/6890187#6890187) answers. However, I think `itertools` provides a slightly more readable alternative, lambda notwithstanding. (For Python 3; for Python 2, use `xrange` instead of `range`).

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> l = list('apples')
>>> l.index('p')
1
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda x: l[x] != 'p', reversed(range(len(l)))))
2
```

This will raise a `StopIteration` exception if the item isn't found; you could catch that and raise a `ValueError` instead, to make this behave [just like `index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Defined as a function, avoiding the `lambda` shortcut:

```
def rindex(lst, item):
    def index_ne(x):
        return lst[x] != item
    try:
        return next(dropwhile(index_ne, reversed(range(len(lst)))))
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("rindex(lst, item): item not in list")
```

It works for non-chars too. Tested:

```
>>> rindex(['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'apples'], 'apples')
3
```

Answer (score 6):

```
last_occurence=len(yourlist)-yourlist[::-1].index(element)-1
```

just easy as that.no need to import or create a function.

Answer (score 6):

#### With `dict`

You can use the fact that dictionary keys are unique and when building one with tuples only the last assignment of a value for a particular key will be used.  As stated in other answers, this is fine for small lists but it creates a dictionary for all unique values and might not be efficient for large lists.

```
dict(map(reversed, enumerate(li)))["a"]

6
```

Answer (score 2):

I came here hoping to find someone had already done the work of writing the most efficient version of `list.rindex`, which provided the full interface of `list.index` (including optional `start` and `stop` parameters). I didn't find  that in the answers to this question, or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522372), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836425), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985096). So I put this together myself... making use of suggestions from other answers to this and the other questions.

```
def rindex(seq, value, start=None, stop=None):
  """L.rindex(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return last index of value.
  Raises ValueError if the value is not present."""
  start, stop, _ = slice(start, stop).indices(len(seq))
  if stop == 0:
    # start = 0
    raise ValueError('{!r} is not in list'.format(value))
  else:
    stop -= 1
    start = None if start == 0 else start - 1
  return stop - seq[stop:start:-1].index(value)
```

The technique using `len(seq) - 1 - next(i for i,v in enumerate(reversed(seq)) if v == value)`, suggested in several other answers, can be more space-efficient: it needn't create a reversed copy of the full list. But in my (offhand, casual) testing, it's about 50% slower.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of answers here, so I thought it'd be interesting to compare different approaches.
I've also came up with a pretty good solution not listed here and created a [PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/rindex/).

Let's get straight to the point, here's the code I've used for benchmarking:

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import dropwhile
from operator import indexOf

from rindex import rindex


def rindex1(li, value):
    return len(li) - 1 - li[::-1].index(value)


def rindex2(li, value):
    for i in reversed(range(len(li))):
        if li[i] == value:
            return i
    raise ValueError("{} is not in list".format(value))


def rindex3(li, value):
    return max(loc for loc, val in enumerate(li) if val == value)


def rindex4(li, value):
    for r_idx, elt in enumerate(reversed(li)):
        if elt == value:
            return len(li) - 1 - r_idx


def rindex5(li, value):
    return next(dropwhile(lambda x: li[x] != value, reversed(range(len(li)))))


def rindex6(li, value):
    return dict(map(reversed, enumerate(li)))[value]


def rindex7(seq, value, start=None, stop=None):
    """L.rindex(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return last index of value.
    Raises ValueError if the value is not present."""
    start, stop, _ = slice(start, stop).indices(len(seq))
    if stop == 0:
        # start = 0
        raise ValueError("{!r} is not in list".format(value))
    else:
        stop -= 1
        start = None if start == 0 else start - 1
    return stop - seq[stop:start:-1].index(value)


# Thanks Kelly Bundy for mentioning this in the comments
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/63834895
def rindex8(li, value):
    return len(li) - 1 - indexOf(reversed(li), value)


def my_rindex(li, value, start=0, stop=None, /):
    size = len(li)
    li.reverse()
    try:
        return (
            size - 1 - li.index(value, 0 if stop is None else size - stop, size - start)
        )
    finally:
        li.reverse()


FUNCTIONS = (rindex, rindex1, rindex2, rindex3, rindex4, rindex5, rindex6, rindex7, rindex8, my_rindex)
FUNCTIONS_WITH_BOUNDARIES = (rindex7, my_rindex, rindex)


def test_correctness():
    li = [0, 1, 0, 2]
    for f in FUNCTIONS:
        assert f(li, 0) == 2
    for f in FUNCTIONS_WITH_BOUNDARIES:
        assert f(li, 0, 0, 1) == 0


def test_speed():
    small = list(range(10))
    big = list(range(1_000_000))
    tests = (
        ("small best", small, len(small) - 1, 1_000_000),
        ("big best", big, len(big) - 1, 100),
        ("small middle", small, len(small) // 2, 1_000_000),
        ("big middle", big, len(big) // 2, 100),
        ("small worst", small, 0, 1_000_000),
        ("big worst", big, 0, 100),
    )
    for name, li, value, repeats in tests:
        print(format(f" {name} ", "=^22"))
        for f in (list.index,) + FUNCTIONS:
            print(
                f.__name__.ljust(10),
                ":",
                format(
                    timeit(
                        "f(li, value)",
                        globals={
                            "f": f,
                            "li": li,
                            "value": value
                            if f is not list.index
                            else len(li) - 1 - value,
                        },
                        number=repeats,
                    ),
                    "9f",
                ),
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_correctness()
    test_speed()
```

And the results:

```
===== small best =====
index      :  0.124899
rindex     :  0.168111
rindex1    :  0.711771
rindex2    :  1.042878
rindex3    :  3.031604
rindex4    :  1.018811
rindex5    :  2.309284
rindex6    :  8.428993
rindex7    :  1.536563
rindex8    :  0.714625
my_rindex  :  0.751303
====== big best ======
index      :  0.000020
rindex     :  0.000030
rindex1    :  2.520536
rindex2    :  0.000187
rindex3    : 12.694951
rindex4    :  0.000135
rindex5    :  0.000276
rindex6    : 82.994252
rindex7    :  2.820221
rindex8    :  0.000113
my_rindex  :  0.619653
==== small middle ====
index      :  0.264816
rindex     :  0.325221
rindex1    :  0.875725
rindex2    :  1.440296
rindex3    :  3.100110
rindex4    :  1.424884
rindex5    :  3.330751
rindex6    :  8.430511
rindex7    :  1.686265
rindex8    :  0.888111
my_rindex  :  0.888112
===== big middle =====
index      :  1.813371
rindex     :  1.747949
rindex1    :  4.465189
rindex2    :  5.886711
rindex3    : 12.696632
rindex4    :  6.856758
rindex5    : 13.855785
rindex6    : 84.861101
rindex7    :  4.457431
rindex8    :  2.044351
my_rindex  :  2.299312
==== small worst =====
index      :  0.452868
rindex     :  0.456035
rindex1    :  1.016495
rindex2    :  1.846306
rindex3    :  3.038056
rindex4    :  1.901025
rindex5    :  4.539291
rindex6    :  8.428476
rindex7    :  1.841232
rindex8    :  1.061607
my_rindex  :  1.054495
===== big worst ======
index      :  3.620210
rindex     :  3.083546
rindex1    :  5.824754
rindex2    : 11.764573
rindex3    : 12.696748
rindex4    : 13.481179
rindex5    : 27.432877
rindex6    : 82.762718
rindex7    :  5.880688
rindex8    :  3.685528
my_rindex  :  3.725783
```

Here, the "best" case means that the searched value is rightmost, "middle" - in the middle, "worst" - leftmost.
Technically, the worst case would be absence of the searched value, but handling of exceptions may mess up the measurements.

`rindex` from my `rindex` package is superior (even beats the built-in `index` in some cases) because it's written in Cython. Use it if you need the best performance.

Comparison of pure Python functions:

We can also exclude `rindex3`, `rindex5` and `rindex6` from the competition: they do not have advantages.

`rindex2` and `rindex4` are almost the same, but 4 is a little faster for "good" cases, and for the "bad" ones it's the opposite.
They're also excluded because `rindex8` is faster in every case.

`rindex1` is probably the best one for small lists (though, `rindex8` and `my_rindex` are only a bit slower).

For other cases `rindex8` is the fastest (even comparable to the built-in `index` in the "big worst" case).

`my_rindex` is almost as fast, but slows down dramatically in the "big best" case.
It supports boundaries, though.

However, if you use boundaries that effectively reduce a big list to a small list, `rindex7` will be your friend.

Comment: You can see another fast one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63834895) (the second one, you already got the first one).

Comment: Beating `list.index` is rather suspicious, makes me think something might be wrong. I see you only inserted the new times. Did you only run the new function? Then maybe your computer was for some reason faster than when you did the previous measurements. When I use your package, is there an easy way for me to tell which of the three implementations is getting used?

Comment: You have a bug. Set up `x = float('nan')` and `xs = [x]`. Then `xs.index(x)` gives me `0` as expected, but `rindex(xs, x)` gives me a ValueError, falsely claiming that the element isn't in the sequence.

Comment: The error traceback tells me that it happened in c_rindex.pyx line 29. Does that answer my earlier question, does that mean I'm running Cython? (Or am I just running your Cython code but maybe in pure Python without Cython? I'm not familiar with Cython, and I'm running it on replit.com, which might or might not have installed Cython for me.)

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, pyx means Cython. I've run the tests a lot of times, so I'm pretty sure about the results. The "bug" you've described is an interesting case. Try `[float("nan")].index(float("nan"))`. According to Python docs, `index` must "Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is equal to x.". But `x != x` if `x` is NaN!

Comment: Where in the docs did you see that? I see *"index of the first occurrence of x in s"*. [Link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations). I ran your benchmark a few times now with just `index` and `rindex`. The latter indeed seems to be consistently a bit faster in the "big worst" test.  But that appears to be because it searches for 0 while `index` searches for 999999. If I change 0 to 1 in the test definition, then `index` seems consistently faster. So it seems searching for 0 is somehow advantageous and not fair.

Comment: Description of list.index, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html. You can see `tests/benchmark.py` in my repository, it shuffles the list for more accurate results and c_rindex is still better according to that.

Comment: Ah, well, that's "only" the tutorial. I'll check out that benchmark...

Comment: That benchmark looks better, yes. Though I get faster times for `index`. [Link](https://dpaste.org/ixMTN). Can you share sample results as well? (Preferably only showing those two functions.)

Comment: This is what I get on my x86_64 Linux https://pastebin.com/2Yv6jtyJ

Comment: Odd that it looks so much better for 10000 and not/less better for the others. Also still suspicious at all. I mean, then you could presumably likewise write a faster `index` function, and that just shouldn't be possible. Already out of principle, as `list.index` should use the fastest possible way. And also because it has access to the list's internal data structure. Or does Cython have that, too? Does it not access the list elements through some more costly interface? Or maybe it's because yours lacks the identity checks, but I don't think they take much time in `list.index`.

Comment: You underestimate Cython ;)
It generates a lot of code to handle different situations and in some cases can be very fast. For example, list.index uses `PyObject_RichCompareBool` that calls `PyObject_RichCompare` internally, checks the result and returns a corresponding value, which means that the value is actually checked twice. The rindex code generated by Cython straight up calls `PyObject_RichCompare`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple loop:

```
def reversed_index(items, value):
    for pos, curr in enumerate(reversed(items)):
        if curr == value:
            return len(items) - pos - 1
    raise ValueError("{0!r} is not in list".format(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Love @alcalde's solution, but faced **ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence** if none of the elements match the condition.

To avoid the error set **default=None**:

```
max((loc for loc, val in enumerate(li) if val == 'a'), default=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def rindex(lst, val):
  try:
    return next(
      len(lst) - n
      for n, v in enumerate(reversed(lst), start=1)
      if v == val
    )
  except StopIteration:
    raise ValueError(f'{val} is not in list')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lastIndexOf = lambda array, item: len(array) - (array[::-1].index(item)) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is small, you can compute all indices and return the largest:

```
index = max(i for i, x in enumerate(elements) if x == 'foo')
```

Answer (score -1):

val = [1,2,2,2,2,2,4,5].

If you need to find last occurence of 2

`last_occurence = (len(val) -1) - list(reversed(val)).index(2)`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a little one-liner for obtaining the last index, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a list comprehension:

```
li = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "x", "d", "a", "6"]
[l[0] for l in enumerate(li) if l[1] == "a"][-1]
```