# How to find the index of only one minimum value in a list containing more than one minimum value

Tags: python

```
a = [2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 7]
```

If one is to find the minimum value in this list (which is `2`) the corresponding indexes of `2` in the list `a` are 0, 1 and 3 respectively.

How to tell python to use the minimum value at the highest index (the number `2` at index 3)?

Comment: Just iterate your list and save the index of the minimal element using <= comparison

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the last occurrence of an item in a Python list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/how-to-find-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply reverse the list using `a[::-1]` and then apply the same technique to find the index. `a[::-1].index(min(a))` will give us the index of minimum value from the end, in order to record the index w.r.t to 0th position(starting of list) we can subtract `a[::-1].index(min(a))` from `len(a) - 1`.

```
a = [2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 7]

print len(a) - a[::-1].index(min(a)) - 1

>>> 3
```

Comment: try `a = [2, 2, 4, 12, 5, 7]` with your string solution

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham I missed that case. apologies.

Answer (score 2):

This can be written as a function `indexes()` and then take the `max()` of the resulting iterator:

**Example:**

```
def indexes(xs, value):
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        if x == value:
            yield i

a = [2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 7]
print max(indexes(a, min(a)))  # 3
```

**Update;** Just as a matter of completeness; if you per se wanted the minimum index for a set of values with more than one minimum you'd just swap out `max()` for `min()` at the front of the expression. So:

```
a = [2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7]
print min(indexes(a, min(a)))  # 2
```

whilst:

```
print max(indexes(a, min(a)))  # 5
```

This is kind of handy and flexible in general :)

Comment: The min should be 3 though, you want the max not the min

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks such a subtle thing to miss; but a really trivial change :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> -min(zip(a, range(0, -len(a), -1)))[1]
3
```

Comment: @Ajay Of course. What good would it do to just repeat someone else :-)

Comment: It's failing for this
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
it should be -6 or 7-6

Comment: @Ajay Dear lord that was embarrassing. Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

use enumerate reversing the list with a start index of `1` calling next in the generator to get the first value, subtracting the index from the length of the list.

```
a = [2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 7]
mn = min(a)

print(len(a) - next(i for i, ele in enumerate(reversed(a),1) if ele == mn))
 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the enumerated list and use the maximum index :

```
In [109]: max([ind for ind, val in enumerate(a) if val==min(a)])
Out[109]: 3
```

Comment: The OP said minimum :)

Comment: OP said max index of minimum value x)

Comment: This is undoubtedly the best technique.

Comment: This is terrible, veeeeeery slow because O(n^2).

Comment: For a list of 5 numbers, I can live with that speed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Find the smallest, then iterate over the list collecting the indices of the matching values.

```
smallest = min(items)
indices = [index for index, value in enumerate(items) if value == smallest]
largest_index = max(indices) # or indices[-1]
```

If you have a very long list then you might want to start from the back and stop once you reach the first item.

```
largest_index = len(items) - next(index for index, value in \
    enumerate(reversed(items), start=1) if value == smallest)
```

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen your answer as it hadn't loaded yet. I made the edit after re-reading the question and seeing he only wanted to largest index of the smallest item.

Answer (score 0):

This might do:

```
(len(a) -1 )- a[: : -1].index(min(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=[2,2,4,2,5,7]

minval=min(a)  #min of a

for l in range(len(a)):

  if a[l]==minval:
    index=l
    continue
print index
```