# Finding an interval from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, count

I have a list of including some cost values for a project. The list `c` says that a project started in year 1 (assuming `c[0] = year 1`, suspended in year 3, and completed at the end of year 4. So, there is no associated cost in year 5.

```
c = [3000000.0, 3000000.0, 0.0, 200000.0, 0.0]
```

From the list, I want to find the project length, which is *basically* **`4`** **not** `3` in the above example based on my way of programming. If the list would be as following:

```
d = [3000000.0, 3000000.0, 100000.0, 200000.0, 0.0]
```

I could have the following to solve my problem:

Input:

```
cc = 0
for i in d:
    if i>0:
        cc += 1
```

Output:
    cc = 4

However, it does not really work when there is a suspension(gap) between two years. Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: What does `cc` refer to ?

Comment: Do you want to include the gap years when counting?

Comment: This snippet gives cc=3 for a list that has a 0 in it. Can you explain why this output is not correct?

Comment: Yes @Neo. It is what I want to do.

Comment: @gogaz `cc` refers to the counter.

Comment: Sorry, I just made it confusing. Let's say the second list is called 'd', which I have already edited in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to find the last index + 1 (index start to 0) which is not 0 you can do :

```
>>> c = [3000000.0, 3000000.0, 0.0, 200000.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> cc=[c.index(i) for i in c if i!=0][-1]+1
>>> cc
4
```

***EDIT :***

you can use `numpy` to not take in account the first 0 in the list:

```
>>> c = [0.0, 0.0, 3000000.0, 3000000.0, 0.0, 200000.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.trim_zeros(c)
[3000000.0, 3000000.0, 0.0, 200000.0]
>>> len(np.trim_zeros(c))
4
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you @Dadep.

Comment: Actually, it is not also working. See the example: `c = [0.0, 0.0, 3000000.0, 200000.0, 0.0]`   Output: `4`. However, based on my logic, it should be `2`.

Comment: Great! Thank you very very much Dadep. You saved me a lot of time. Otherwise, I was gonna apply my method I mentioned to @gogaz.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to find the position of last `0` in the list.
Look at  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/how-to-find-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-python-list)

What I think is the best approach from the link above is:
`last_0 = max(loc for loc, val in enumerate(c) if val == 0)`

You can also calculate the first `0`:
`first_0 = min(loc for loc, val in enumerate(c) if val == 0)`

And their difference is the length.

In one block:

```
zeros_indices = [loc for loc, val in enumerate(c) if val == 0]
length = max(zeros_indices) - min(zeros_indices)
```

Comment: It fails for: `c = [0.0, 0.0, 3000000.0, 200000.0, 0.0]`. I am expecting to have `2`. It yields `4`.

Comment: @user8028576 You'd better specify it initially... Anyway, added.

Answer (score 0):

You could look backwards through the list until you find the index of an element which has a value greater than zero, and if you add one to that index it will be the length in years with gaps allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To include gap years to your counting, you can check that the current item is not the last one in the list.

You would better do this by iterating over indexes instead of elements to avoid having to find out your position within the list at each iteration.

```
cc = 0
for i in xrange(len(c)):
    if c[i] > 0 and i < (len(c) - 1):
        cc += 1
```

The `xrange` function generates  a `list` from `0` to `len(c)`. You could eihter use `range` instead but `range` keeps the generated list in memory while `xrange` does not.

EDIT: This does not handle multiple zeros at the end of the list `c`

Comment: Input: `c = [3000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 200000.0]` Output: 1. However, I am expecting 5 that is why not working.

Comment: This is true but not mentionned in your question

Comment: I thought "suspended in year 3" means: 0 cost is counted after the project started. Actually, while answering this, I got how the logic should be programmed. First, I need to search for the starting year, where the first value>0 is the starting point in the list. Then, I find the last value>0 in the list. The range gives me the project length.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = [3000000.0, 3000000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 200000.0, 0.0]

cc = 0
templength = 0
for i in reversed(c):
  if i == 0:
    templength += 1
  else:
    break
print (len(c)-templength)
```

output:

```
5
```

Comment: What I want the output to be is `5` in your example.

Comment: fixed the code, sorry. I did not realize that my code had a bug.