# find the index of the first coincidence in a list giving a starting position but backward

Tags: python

Is there any pythonic way to find the first coincidence before a giving index?

For example I want to find the `2` that go before the `1`, and the the `2` that go after the `1`.

```
a = [0,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0]
```

for the `2` that go after the 1 I use this `a.index(2,4)`.

Is there any easy or clean way to do it?

Comment: You want to find 2 closest to 1 on the left and 2 closest to 1 on the right?

Comment: @ThatBird yes, exaclty

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/how-to-find-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-python-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reverse the list and calculate the index of your "pivot" element in the reversed list, then use `index` as normal:

```
def find_before(lst, e, idx):
    new_idx = len(lst) - idx - 1
    return len(lst) - lst[::-1].index(e, new_idx) - 1
```

It's worth noting that this is a bad idea for huge lists because it temporarily creates a copy when it reverses it. A better idea for that scenario is what blhsing did, which is just stepping backwards through the list:

```
def find_before(lst, e, idx):
    i = idx
    while i > 0:
        i -= 1
        if lst[i] == e:
        return i
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"No element {e} found before index {idx}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to do it yourself since there's no built-in function for the equivalent of `str.rindex` for lists:

```
def rindex(lst, x, start=-1, end=0):
    if start < 0:
        start += len(lst)
    i = start
    while i >= end and lst[i] != x:
        i -= 1
    if i < 0:
        raise ValueError()
    return i

a = [0,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0]
print(rindex(a, 2, 4))
```

This outputs:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

In O(n) you can build a `dict` that holds all positions of any element of your list:

```
a = [0,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0]

pos = {}

for idx, elem in  enumerate(a):
    pos.setdefault(elem,set())
    pos[elem].add(idx)    

print(pos) # {0: {0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8}, 2: {1, 7}, 1: {4}}
```

Finding the position of one element is just one O(1) operation away:

```
print(pos[2])  # {1,7}
```

If you want the first and last occurence, you can do:

```
print(min(pos[0]),max(pos[0])  #  0 8
```

You can query other things as well:

```
# get index of first 2 that is before the 1st 1
print( min(x for x in pos[2] if x < min(pos[1])))  # 1

# get index of all 0s that are after the 1st 1
print( list(x for x in pos[0] if x > min(pos[1])))  # [5, 6, 8]
```

As for the 2 before 1st 1 and after 1st 1:

```
firstOneIdx = min(pos[1]) # calc min index of 1 before, so it is not recalc'ed
print( "2 before 1st 1:" , list(x for x in pos[2] if x < firstOneIdx))
print( "2 after  1st 1:" , list(x for x in pos[2] if x > firstOneIdx))
```

which outputs:

```
2 before 1st 1: [1]
2 after  1st 1: [7]
```

You can use `min/max` to reduce the lists to 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be broken down into three sub-operations: split the array into two sub-arrays and then search the first from the end and search the second from the beginning.

```
def index(array, value, pivot):

    def find(array):
        return array.index(value)

    first_half = arr[ (pivot - 1) : : -1 ]
    last_half = arr[ (pivot + 1) : ]
    return [ pivot - find(first_half) - 1, pivot + find(last_half) + 1 ]
```

In essence, this method splits your array around `pivot` and rearranges the first sub-array backwards. After that, you simply find the first occurrence of `value` in both, which corresponds to the closest occurrence of `value` to `pivot` in the array. It would work like this:

```
indexes = index(array, 2, 4)
# [1, 7]
```