# How to get index of the last item with a given value

Tags: python

In a list of integer values

```
a = [4, 8, 2, 3, 8, 5, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 2, 1, 3]
```

I have to find the index of the last item with value `8`. Is there more elegant way to do that rather than mine:

```
a = [4, 8, 2, 3, 8, 5, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 2, 1, 3]

for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
    if a[i] == 8:
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: You need `10` as output, means last index of 8 in array

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey, yes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the last occurrence of an item in a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/how-to-find-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
a = [4, 8, 2, 3, 8, 5, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 2, 1, 3]
index = len(a) - 1 - a[::-1].index(8)
```

Just reverse the array and find first index of element and then subtract it from length of array.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lst = [4, 8, 2, 3, 8, 5, 8, 8, 1, 4, 8, 2, 1, 3]
>>> next(i for i in range(len(lst)-1, -1, -1) if lst[i] == 8)
10
```

This throws `StopIteration` if the list doesn't contain the search value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` on all indexes of items with a value of `8` and take the last value, or using `reverse = True` take the first value

```
x = sorted(i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == 8)[-1]

print(x) # => 10
```