# How can i move more than one item from one list to another in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I would like to move more than one item from one list to another.

```
list1 = ['2D','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ']
list2 = ['XX','XX','5D','4S','3D','  ','  ','  ','  ']
list3 = ['XX','XX','XX','8C','7H','6C','  ','  ','  ']
```

In the code above `'  '` is a double space

I would like to be able to move `'5D','4S','3D'` from `list2` onto `'8C','7H','6C'` in `list3`.

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
list1 = ['2D','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ']
list2 = ['XX','XX','5D','4S','3D','  ','  ','  ','  ']
list3 = ['XX','XX','XX','8C','7H','6C','  ','  ','  ']


items_to_be_moved = list2[list2.index('XX')+2 : list2.index('  ')]

list3[list3.index('  ')] = items_to_be_moved
del list2[list2.index('XX')+2 : list2.index('  ')]

print('list2',list2)
print('list3',list3)
```

and this returns

```
list2 ['XX', 'XX', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']
list3 ['XX', 'XX', 'XX', '8C', '7H', '6C', ['5D', '4S', '3D'], '  ', '  ']
```

However, i dont want to use `list2.index('XX')+2`, i would like to use a code that gives the last index of `'XX'` just like `list2.index('  ')` gives the first index of `'  '`.

Also, i dont want the moved items to be in a separate list of their own within another list. 
For example: instead of returning

```
"list3 ['XX', 'XX', 'XX', '8C', '7H', '6C', ['5D', '4S', '3D'], '  ', '  ']"
```

the list

```
"list3 ['XX', 'XX', 'XX', '8C', '7H', '6C','5D', '4S', '3D', '  ', '  ']"
```

should be returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace the correct items, use slice assignment.

```
list1 = ['2D','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ','  ']
list2 = ['XX','XX','5D','4S','3D','  ','  ','  ','  ']
list3 = ['XX','XX','XX','8C','7H','6C','  ','  ','  ']

list3[3:6] = list2[2:5]

print list3
# ['XX', 'XX', 'XX', '5D', '4S', '3D', '  ', '  ', '  ']
```

If you want to start from after the final consecutive `'XX'`, you can use:

```
from itertools import takewhile
i = sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda elem: elem == 'XX', list3))

list3[i:i+3] = list2[i-1:i+2]
```

to find the index of the last one.

Comment: I would like to use indexing, because this is to be used in a function.

Comment: this doesn't solve the asker question about dynamically finding the last 'xx' index

Comment: @CodeBisector I've added how to find the index.

Comment: nice one with itertools also I think @turek suggestion is more pythonic

Comment: @alonisser See my comment on his answer. It probably doesn't really matter, but I don't like making a copy of the list if not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

well if all of the 'xx' are always before the needed there is another way (beside the one suggested by @turek) using 'list.count('xx')' and the slicing :

```
list[count-1:count+2]
```

you can use the slice operator to do the insert also I would probably iterate like suggested by @intra-c

Answer (score 1):

First, here's how to [find the last index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522372/finding-first-and-last-index-of-some-value-in-a-list-in-python).  But beware, if you get the index number of the last copy of `XX`, what if the list reads, e.g., `['XX', '1D', 'XX', '4S']` so that there's a valid item in the middle?

Anyway, once you have a span that you want to move from one list to another, you need only use the slice operator to do the insert and delete:

```
>>> list2[2:5]
['5D', '4S', '3D']
>>> list3[6:6] = list2[2:5]
>>> list3
['XX', 'XX', 'XX', '8C', '7H', '6C', '5D', '4S', '3D', '  ', '  ', '  ']
```

You can use `del` to remove from list2, or you can just assign to the slice:

```
>>> list2[2:5] = []
>>> list2
['XX', 'XX', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']
```

Comment: Doing the slice assignment right over the old values is fast because you don't have to resize the list and move values. Your method makes you move all the values after that point in the list twice. The linked method of finding the last index also requires you to make a copy of the list, and iterate over the whole list, which isn't necessary.

Comment: It sounded like he wanted the new (output) list to be bigger, not overwritten.  It's a little confusing because his sample input `list3` has ten items and his sample output has 11, which does not match either a pure-insert or a pure-overwrite.  (I'm surprised the step-by-negative-one slice method is not special cased inside Python.  Still, as I noted, there's the danger of taking things that are not-XX but are surrounded by the XX markers.  Your `takewhile` is the obvious right way to get contiguous XX items, especially since `itertools` are generally very fast.)

Comment: Gah, I went back and re-read the inputs, outputs, and problem, and I'm entirely wrong, he did say "overwrite".

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through with

```
for item in items_to_be_moved:
    # Add items one at a time
```

Answer (score 0):

On the second topic:

Don't think there's a function for finding last occurance in lists, but you could either do a loop

```
pos = 0
while 1:
    try:
        pos = list3.index('XX',pos+1)
    except ValueError:
        break
if pos == 0 and list3[0] != 'XX':
    #Do something to pos if there was no XX in list...
```

or reverse the list in-place do the index-thing reverse it back and recalc the position.

```
list3.reverse()
pos = list3.index('XX')
list3.reverse()
pos = len(list3) - pos - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about negative indices for slicing from the end:

```
i2_begin = -list2[::-1].index('XX')
i2_end = list2.index('  ')
i3 = list3.index('  ')

list3[i3:i3] = list2[i2_begin:i2_end]
del list2[i2_begin:i2_end]
```