# Python list.index() from end of the list

Tags: list, python-2.7

In python, if I have a list say `[2,1,1,3,5]`, then is it possible to get

`[2,1,1,3,5].index(1)` as `2` i.e first match starting from the higher end instead of the lower?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivelant to rindex for lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836425/equivelant-to-rindex-for-lists-in-python)

Comment: Yeah, its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890170/python-how-to-find-last-occurrence-in-a-list-in-python , could someone close it?

Answer (score 1):

Can't say I've ever needed to do this, but you could always hack it with:

```
lst = [2,1,1]
reverseindex = len(lst)-1 - lst[::-1].index(1)
```

Note that if you had a STRING, you could do:

```
string = "21135"
reverseindex = string.rindex(1)
# reverseindex == 2
```

But lists don't have this function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about list order being preserved, you could always use `lst.reverse()` before `lst.index(1)`.

[Documentation is on the official site](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: The documentation does not even say that `list.index()` has a start_at attribute