# Better way to return the index of an element from a list, with element BEHIND preferred

Tags: python, list, indexing

for example, there is a list:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,2,1]
print(numbers.index(1))
```

output is
`0`

*element behind is preferred* means that, the index of the "1" at the end should be printed instead of the the "1" at the beginning.
i.e.
output should be `5`

A baseline method of "reverse the list" is provided bellow, it there a faster & simpler way to do this?

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,2,1]
numbers.reverse()
output = []
for i in range(1,4):
    inv_inx= len(numbers)-numbers.index(i)-1
    output.append(inv_inx)
print(output)
assert output == [5, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that doesn't make any temporary `list`s, scans from the end (so it doesn't find all the `1`s you don't care about) and short-circuits (so it stops when the element is found) is to combine a generator expression with the `next`, `reversed` and `enumerate` built-ins:

```
def rindex(seq, value):
    return len(seq) - next(i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(seq), 1) if x == value)
```

This will raise `StopIteration` if the value is not found, if you want it to raise `ValueError`, you just have to convert it:

```
def rindex(seq, value):
    try:
        return len(seq) - next(i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(seq), 1) if x == value)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError(f"{value!r} is not in {type(seq).__name__}")  # Rough equivalent to list.index message
```

For comparison, a version without a generator expression or `next` would look like this:

```
def rindex(seq, value):
    for i, x in enumerate(reversed(seq), 1):
        if x == value:
            return len(seq) - i
    raise ValueError(f"{value!r} is not in {type(seq).__name__}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the search from the end of the list:

The list `index()` method can take a maximum of three arguments:

**element** - the element to be searched

**start** (optional) - start searching from this index

**end** (optional) - search the element up to this index

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,2,1]
print(numbers.index(1,-1))
```

OUTPUT:

```
5
```

EDIT:

If the search item is not in the end of the list:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,2,1,2]

print(len(lst)-1 - lst[::-1].index(1))   # 5
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793248/python-list-index-from-end-of-the-list)

Comment: @Chris point taken. will edit.

Answer (score 0):

try this not the best solution but better.

```
numbers = [1,2,1,4,2,1]
count=0
for i in numbers :
    count=count+1
    if i == 1:
        a=[]
        a.append(count-1)
print(a)    #5
```