# Pythonic way to delete all values past last index of "x" in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I *have* searched for a similar topic, as I assume someone must have come across this problem before. Any links to relevant topics are appreciated :)

I want to delete all values past (and including) the last index of "x".

Given the list: `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Do something, e.g. `del a[a.rindex(2):]`

And end up with `a == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]` - Note that the 2 is deleted

Comment: You want to delete all the items of a list form where you find a given value?

Comment: I want to delete all the values in a list after the last occurrence of a given value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def last_index(a,target):
    for i in a:
        check = a[-1]
        a.pop()
        if check == target :
            break
    return a
```

EDIT
Thanks to the comments, this can be made more simple like this :

```
def last_index(a,target):
    while a.pop() != target : pass
    return a
```

Comment: Very nice. Just a small suggestion: `for _ in a:` would be more pythonic: 1. Unused variables in loops are usually called `_`, 2. No need to create a new `range` object (in Python 3) or a new list (in Python 2) which is what `range(len(a))` does.

Comment: The function name `last_index` suggests that it will just return the index, while it's actually also modifying the original list.

Comment: I ended up using this, but not as a function. It was `for _ in a:` | `a.pop()` | `if a[-1] == 0:` | `break`, where the |s are line breaks

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks, I'm also on my way to make my codes more pythonic, and your comments really helped me out! I usually use len(range(list)) when I need index of the current item, but this is not necessary for this case I guess.

Comment: @Mike @DeepSpace, you could combine the `a.pop(); check = a[-1]` couldn't you? `check = a.pop() ; while check != target: ; check = a.pop()` That deletes the target as well.

Comment: @DarkMatterMatt Correct, `pop` returns the removed object.

Comment: even shorter: `while a.pop() != target: pass`

Answer (score 2):

There is no `rindex` in Python and index returns the index of the `first` occurrence.

Using `len(a) - a[::-1].index(2)` (the first occurrence from the end is the last occurrence) will return the index of the last occurrence of `2` so we can use slicing:

```
li = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
element = 2
last_index = len(li) - li[::-1].index(element)
li = li[:last_index - 1]
print(li)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]
```

Note that this approach isn't the best in the performance department since it needs to create a list in memory and then reverse it.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,4,2,3,4,5,2,3]

def delete_last_index(list,n):
  index = len(a) - 1 - a[::-1].index(n)
  return list[:index]

a = delete_last_index(a,2)
print(a)
```

This should give:
`[1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to so something you might want:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> last = len(a) - a[::-1].index(2) - 1
>>> last
8
>>> a[:last]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]
```

based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438901/finding-the-last-occurrence-of-an-item-in-a-list-python).

*EDIT*

Alternatively if saving memory is an issue, you can iterate over the list and pop element by element. This will be more time-consuming, but less memory-consuming.

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> while a[-1] != 2:
...   a.pop()
... 
5
4
3
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]
>>> a.pop()
2
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]
```