# Last index of duplicate items in a python list

Tags: python, list

Does anyone know how I can get the last index position of duplicate items in a python list containing duplicate and non-duplicate items? 
I have a list sorted in ascending order with `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]` 
I want it to print the last index of duplicate items and index on non-duplicate items like this

```
2
4
6
7
8
```

I tried doing this way but could only print the starting index of duplicate elements and misssed non-duplicate items.

> ```
> id_list = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
> for i in range(len(id_list)):
>     for j in range(i+1,len(id_list)):
>         if id_list[i]==id_list[j]:
>             print(i)
> ```

Comment: Is the list always sorted?

Comment: @slider  Yes the list is always sorted in ascending order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding first and last index of some value in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522372/finding-first-and-last-index-of-some-value-in-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop on the list using `enumerate` to get indexes & values, and use a dictionary and retain the last index (last index "wins" when there are duplicates). In the end, sort the indexes (as dictionaries aren't ordered, but you can use an `OrderedDict`):

```
import collections

lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
d = collections.OrderedDict()

for i,v in enumerate(lst):
    d[v] = i

print(list(d.values()))
```

prints:

```
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

The advantage of this solution is that it works even if the duplicates aren't consecutive.

Python 3.7 guarantees the order of the base dictionaries so a simple dict comprehension solves it:

```
{v:i for i,v in enumerate(lst)}.values()
```

Comment: Or just `{x:i for i,x in enumerate(lst)}`, particularly in newer version of Python where `dict` retains insertion order.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerate` and check the next index in the list. If an element is not equal to the element in the next index, it is the last duplicate:

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
result = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i == len(lst) - 1 or x != lst[i + 1]]

print(result)
# [2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). The last value will *always* be in scope, so we can include this at the end explicitly.

```
L = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]

res = [idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(L, L[1:])) if i != j] + [len(L) - 1]

print(res)

# [2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```