# python get indexes of where number starts and ends in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a `query` which is a list of numbers. I want to get the ranges of indices in which the number `1` appears. The range starts when `1` appears and ends on the index in which it doesn't appear. I have made an example to illustrate this.

```
query= [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]

answer = [[5,8],[9,10],[12,14]]
```

**Note: I am not looking for the first and last index of some value in a list in Python. I'm looking for all the places in which they start and end.**

Update: From some of the suggested answers below it looks like **Itertools** is quite handy for this stuff.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522372/finding-first-and-last-index-of-some-value-in-a-list-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding first and last index of some value in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522372/finding-first-and-last-index-of-some-value-in-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @caiomcg I don't think this is the same thing as I'm not looking for the first and last occurrence of 1, I'm looking for all the regions where they are joined together.

Comment: @bharatk see above

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You can implement the algorithm by looking at the first occurence and iterating from that position until the number is no longer what you were searching for and doing it recursively for new occurences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.dropwhile` to do this.

```
>>> query = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]
>>> n = 1
>>>
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> itr = enumerate(query)
>>> [[i, next(dropwhile(lambda t: t[1]==n, itr), [len(query)])[0]] for i,x in itr if x==n]
[[5, 8], [9, 10], [12, 14]]
```

Comment: Interesting... but without the final `0` it fails with `StopIteration`

Comment: Good catch... Fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this. Use `enumerate` to get the indices, then `groupby` the actual value, then filter by the value, finally get the first and last index from the group.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> query = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]
>>> [(g[0][0], g[-1][0]+1) for g in (list(g) for k, g in
...   groupby(enumerate(query), key=lambda t: t[1]) if k == 1)]
...
[(5, 8), (9, 10), (12, 14)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
query= [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]
first = 0 # Track the first index in the current group
ingroup = False # Track whether we are currently in a group of ones
answer = []
for i, e in enumerate(query):
    if e:
        if not ingroup:
            first = i
    else:
        if ingroup:
            answer.append([first, i])
    ingroup = e
if ingroup:
    answer.append([first, len(query)])
```

```
>>> answer
[[5, 8], [9, 10], [12, 14]]
```

I think you probably want something like this.

Comment: That does work. I was wondering if there were any in-built functions or library methods that do this in less lines/more concisely.

Comment: @piccolo I see what you mean. I'll look some more and see if I find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use basic for loop and if statement where are you checking 
where the series of '0' changes to a series of '1' and vice versa

```
query= [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]

r_0 = []
r_1 = []

for i in range(len(query)-1):
    if query[i] == 0 and query[i+1] == 1:
        r_0.append(i+1) # [5, 9, 12]
    if query[i] == 1 and query[i + 1] == 0:
        r_1.append(i + 1) # [8, 10, 14]

print (list(zip(r_0,r_1)))
```

output:

```
[(5, 8), (9, 10), (12, 14)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. Its a solution without foor-loops

```py
from itertools import chain

query = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]

result = list(zip(
    filter(lambda i: query[i] == 1 and (i == 0 or query[i-1] != 1), range(len(query))),
    chain(filter(lambda i: query[i] != 1 and query[i-1] == 1, range(1, len(query))), [len(query)-1])
))
print(result)
```

The output is:

```sh
[(2, 3), (5, 8), (9, 10), (12, 14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share a recursive approach

```
query= [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]

def findOccurrences(of, at, index=0, occurrences=None):
    if occurrences == None: occurrences = [] # python has a weird behavior over lists as the default
                                           # parameter, unfortunately this neets to be done

    try:
        last = start = query.index(of, index)

        for i in at[start:]:
            if i == of:
                last += 1
            else:
                break

        occurrences.append([start, last])
        return findOccurrences(of, at, last, occurrences)
    except:
        pass
    return occurrences


print(findOccurrences(1, query))
print(findOccurrences(1, query, 0)) # Offseting
print(findOccurrences(0, query, 9)) # Offseting with defaul list
```