# How can I order a list based on another lists order?

Tags: python, list

I have a strange problem so I'll just demo it for you to make it easier to understand. I have two lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 20, 6, 210]
>>> b = [20, 6, 1]
```

The result I'm looking for is 3 (position of last matching item in list a based on matches in b)

b always has less data as it contains all duplicates of list a. I want to know what item in B matches the furthest in list a.  So in this example, it would be 6 as 6 is furthest in the list of A.

Is there an easy way to do this - my initial approach is a nested loop but I suspect there's a simpler approach?

Comment: Here's a simple one `sorted(b, key=a.index)[-1]`

Comment: You can also use `sort_together` from more_itertools

Comment: For the specific case described, the simplest (if not necessarily most efficient) code is just `max(b, key=a.index)` (or `b.sort(key=a.index)`/`sorted(b, key=a.index)` if you need the whole list sorted, not just the maximum value as described).

Comment: If you use map for  b; then you can do it in O(n) ie no nested loops

Comment: @ShadowRanger What if `a = [6, 2, 20, 6, 210]` ? Note the 6 at the beginning.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: You use [one of the techniques for simulating `rindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522372/364696) instead.

Comment: @AndrejKesely good point. in my case, I removed dups from both lists but good question.

Comment: @Lostsoul If you removed the duplicates even from `a`, then `a.index` will do.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I'm not sure why the question was closed when the recommended question did not solve my question. I wish you guys could have posted actual answers and gotten the upvotes but regardless, thank you very much for solving my issue. @ShadowRanger's answer would have been accepted.

Comment: Do you want the position or the item? Your question says both, isn't quite clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest (if not necessarily most efficient) code is just:

```
 max(b, key=a.index)
```

or if you want the whole `list` sorted, not just the maximum value as described, one of:

```
b.sort(key=a.index)
```

or

```
sorted(b, key=a.index)
```

If duplicates in the reference `list` are a possibility and you need to get the last index of a value, replace `index` with [one of these simulations of `rindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522372/364696).

**Update**: Addressing your requirement for getting the position, not the value, there is an alternative way to solve this that would involve less work. It's basically a modification of [one of the better solutions to emulating `rindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522372/364696):

```
bset = frozenset(b)
last_a_index = len(a) - next(i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(a), 1) if x in bset)
```

This gets the work down to `O(m + n)` (vs. `O(m * n)` for other solutions) and it short-circuits the loop over `a`; it scans in reverse until it finds a value in `b` then immediately produces the index. It can trivially be extended to produce the value with `a[last_a_index]`, since it doesn't really matter where it was found in `b`. More complex code, but faster, particularly if `a`/`b` might be huge.

Comment: @superbrain: Yeah, that wasn't in the original question, and the comment said they liked my solution, so I just posted it. Edited to add an efficient index producing solution (that can also produce the value with theoretically better performance for larger inputs, though for small inputs, [your simple code that pushes the work to the C layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63830948/364696) is almost certainly faster; I up-voted it).

Comment: Thank you so much @shadowRanger  - for me either position or value is good. Thanks for showing me how to do both options.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't realize that was added. A maybe simpler alternative to your efficient solution: `next(i for i in reversed(range(len(a))) if a[i] in bset)`

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for the *position*:

```
>>> max(map(a.index, b))
3
```